# What is the best way to debug JavaScript and CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, debugging

There are quite a few tools out there to debug JavaScript and CSS.  Firebug, "Alert" messages, Script Debugger, MSE7.exe

I was wondering if anyone could chime in on which one happens to be the best and easiest tool to debug JavaScript and CSS issues?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As for CSS, Firebug has "Style" and "Computed" tabs. Just select an element, and inspect those tabs. I cannot think of any CSS issue that cannot be resolved with these.

[image: Styles tab]

[image: Computed tab]

Answer (score 6):

Firebug and Chrome Dev tools are pretty much the gold standard client side.

Chrome docs:

http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/overview.html

Firebug docs:

http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: Are these two like the "Coke" and "Pepsi"...meaning they both have exactly the same tools but it is a matter of preference?

Comment: Yes, the skills for both are transferable. The thing to remember, though, is that browsers behave differently so you need to test in both and thus need to have at least some familiarity with both tools.

Answer (score 2):

For me, using Firebug (especially in Firefox) is the best solution.

Instead of using Alert messages have you tried console.log('your message')? This will save you clicking alert windows and output messages in the firebug console.

Answer (score 2):

My personal choise is Chrome with its developer tools. Inspect element for css debugging, and Scripts tab for javascript source debugging. You may also use Console for js logging

But actually, web site should support debugging too. In production versions, generally both css and js files are minimized and concatenated, which is hard to debug.

Comment: I see a lot of people use Firebug.  Is this truly better?

Comment: @AnnSanderson actually I don't think that you can compare those. It's just the matter of taste. I'm pretty sure both of then can do everything you wish for debugging purposes.

Comment: Is there a way in either Firebug or Chrome to modify the JavaScript as you debug it and save it to the original file?

Answer (score 1):

Firefox : Firebug
IE : F12 and alert

Comment: F12 is not useful for XPath stuff, unfortunately.  Please prove me wrong, I've been looking everywhere in IE for Xpath tools.

Answer (score 1):

I am an avid Firebug user, but another think you should consider is linting (validate against rules and best practices).  This will not only help you learn some best practices but can also help identify coding issues before you get to the browser.

Here is a [web based js lint tool](http://www.jslint.com/) which you have to paste your code into. Another alternative would be to find a plugin or extension for your IDE. For example, if you were an [eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) user, you can [install the jslint plugin](http://www.andyjamesdavies.com/javascript/installing-jslint-on-eclipse-ide) and check your code as you write it.

Answer (score 1):

IE F12 is too slow to debug. With a heavy web apps, the browser will freeze for ages.